# Python load multiple objects into mapping to use in memcache

Tags: python, mapping, memcached

This code works:

```
   for num in range(1,4):
        results = memcache.get("link_" + str(num))
        output.write('An anonymous person wrote: <blockquote>%s</blockquote>' % results.date)
    return output.getvalue()
```

This code is not working:

```
results = memcache.get_multi(linkKeys,"link_")
for results in results:
    output.write('An anonymous person wrote: <blockquote>%s</blockquote>' % results.date)
return output.getvalue()
```

Can someone explain to me why using memcache.get_multi returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 515, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "C:\Main.py", line 28, in get
    values.write(self.RenderValue())
  File "C:\Main.py", line 57, in RenderValue
    output.write('An anonymous person wrote: <blockquote>%s</blockquote>' % results.date)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'date'
```

Thanks to anyone that helps me solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

for result**s** in result**s** ??

Answer (score 0):

memcache can only store pickleable objects. Can you safely pickle a `GqlQuery` result? If not, you may need to convert it to a `dict` first before handing it off to memcache.

See the [pickle docs](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) and probably the relevant GAE docs.

You may also want to benchmark this and see if using memcache is really helping.